# Git: Backup uncommitted changes to remote repository

Tags: git, backup

I want to backup local, uncommitted changes to the remote repository in order to backup the changes (in case the local hard drive breaks etc.)

(In TFSC, I would have just "shelved" the changes into a shelveset (which "lives" on the TF server))

What I tried:

- I created a new branch "backup_2021-02-13" and switched to it
- I committed the changes.
- I pushed it to the remote repo.

At this point of time, my changes have been saved on the remote repository (meaning that I could recover the information in case of a broken local hard drive)

But now I have the following problem:
Both in the "master" branch as well as in the "backup_2021-02-13" branch, I cannot see the previously pending changes: I can't see them on the backup branch because they have already been committed (yes, the changes are there, but already committed). I can't see them on the master branch because there, these changes do not exist at all.

**But I want to continue working as if the backup process never happened (with all uncommitted changes still being uncommitted).**

So, what I did was, I merged the changes from the backup branch to the master branch (no-commit, ff-only, squash). This way, I have my uncommitted changes in the master branch as uncommitted changes, as it was before any backup work.

But I doubt that this is the normal way of doing this.

**So, what is the correct (and easiest) way to backup local uncommitted changes to a remote repository, but at the same time leaving the current (master) branch as it is (with all the uncommitted changes still being uncommitted)?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your process is ok. After switching to `master` you just need to restore changes committed in the backup branch:

```
git checkout master
git checkout backup_2021-02-13 -- .
```

The 2nd command restores all file from branch `backup_2021-02-13`. Continue working.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works! :-) However, I do not really understand why/how. In the documentation https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout I even do not know which of the 7 git checkout alternatives your solution is using. (Seems again, I am not clever enough for Git... :-| )

Comment: `git checkout` is rather confusing, so in modern `git` it is split into `git switch` (branches) and `git restore` (files). In the answer `git checkout master` switches branch (the 1st alternative in the docs) while `git checkout backup_2021-02-13 -- .` restores all files from the named branch to the current directory (the 7th); single dot here is the current directory.

Comment: Or isn't it the 5th alternative?
In my docs, the 5th is:
git checkout [-f|--ours|--theirs|-m|--conflict=<style>] [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>…​
while the 7th is:
git checkout (-p|--patch) [<tree-ish>] [--] [<pathspec>…​]

Comment: @eikuh Yep, [5 and 6](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutem-f--ours--theirs-m--conflictltstylegtlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203).

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @phd is correct and probably the right one for your needs. Just consider that it is a partial backup, including your working directory only. What I am saying is that doing that you are losing the changes of the index. Instead, to store the changes of the index too, you would need to create a further commit. So, starting from the master:

```
git checkout -b my_backup
git commit -m "first the index"
git add .
git commit -m "and now the working dir"
git checkout --detach HEAD
git reset HEAD~1
git reset --soft master
git checkout master
```

It is quite long but you could move it inside a script (perhaps with parameters for the backup branch name and the current branch) and it is easy to understand too.
`git stash` does a similar thing, but the script would have been a little more complex and I am not sure the `stash` logic won't be different in the future. Currently, a full stash creates 3 commits: one with the index, one with untracked changes and another one which is a merge commit of the previous two and of the `HEAD` itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I must admit, I don't know exactly what you mean by "you are losing the changes of the index". I've found two definitions of "git index" on the internet: (A) The staging area, (B) A file/directory index of the whole workspace. (Probably, A and B are somehow related and thus the same) If you mean (A) I will lose the information which files were in the staging area, then I don't really care because this information is not so important for me. If you mean (B), then is Git not automatically taking care about the index of each repository?

Comment: Think of the index as everything that is going to be committed next. You should care about it because it is important to keep your history clear with the minimum effort. You may have made many changes to your working directory but you do not want to include them all in a single commit, so you move, for each commit, some changes to the index, and then you commit. I suggest you to get used to work with the index :)

Comment: That does not really make sense to me. The information what is inside the staging area and what not, is not very precious. If my harddrive crashes, then I just would have to look at all the uncommitted files and decide again what I want to commit next. So, I don't see a reason to backup the information what is inside the staging area.

Comment: As I said, the accepted answer is the right one for your needs. I just add my answer because in order to completely backup the git repository, you would have to backup the index too. Moreover, suppose that you have already done some partial add (`git add -p`), you do not want to do them again.

Comment: In my workflow I add changes to the staging area shortly before commit so it does not make much sense to backup this. Is it a common practice to build the staging area for a long time before the commit?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. In order to save your changes to remote, you'd have to commit to a non-master branch and push (e.g. backup_2021-02-13)

What most people do is do development in a branch until you are completely done, then merge your changes to Master (ff, squashed) like you did. This development branch is essentially day-to-day "shelved" changes.

To see the pending changes in your branch you just "git diff master" to see the changes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! However, I will accept phd's answer as it fits better in my usual workflow to have the pending changes in the master branch and not in the second branch (using Visual Studio 2019 to see the pending changes).

Comment: I thought that normally every commit should contain a working code - even in a development branch. This is not a case of backups. You cannot always finish with a working code at the time you need to create a backup. Or am I missing something?